# How to uninstall Covenant Eyes?

Tags: macos, applications

I have Covenant Eyes installed and its the worst possible thing ever. It was supposed to be a porn blocker but it didn't necessarily work great, and now is just a pesky blocker that I can't find a way to uninstall.

[image: the only way to see the app is this here and theres nothing that opens when you open the app]

When I try to uninstall it, it just fights back somehow, for example when I tried to use force quit and finder, it gave the error of "app is still running cannot move to trash". Naturally I tried to hit the terminal to uninstall it but cant figure out what to do from here, as I got this message when I tried to kill it this way.

[image: Terminal]

Upon force quit using activity monitor the application does close for more than 3 seconds before turning itself off, and is also accompanied by 3 similar apps that do the exact same thing.

Now I believe this program is essentially un-removable, and It will not be able to be removed without wiping my Mac, but I didn't want to do that quite yet for obvious reasons. Any help to closing this and uninstalling using the terminal would be appreciated

Comment: Boot into [Safe Mode](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/start-up-your-mac-in-safe-mode-mh21245/mac) and then use a tool like [AppCleaner](http://freemacsoft.net/appcleaner/) to remove it completely

Answer (score 2):

Covenant Eyes has some protection against just removing it (which makes sense, given how it works). It comes with an uninstaller which can be used to remove the application. See [How do I uninstall Covenant Eyes on a Mac](https://support.covenanteyes.com/hc/en-us/articles/12620639645851-How-do-I-uninstall-Covenant-Eyes-on-a-Mac-) for details.